# How to use chroot function in C programming?

Tags: c, linux, chroot

I know that use the command "chroot" in linux need some files or directories such as `usr`, `bin` and so   on. But when I use the function `chroot()` in C, do I need these files?

Here is my code, which "hw.out" is a binary file which just print "Hello, world". I compiled it and run it as root, but it was failed to print "Hello, world". What else should I do? Thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int result = chroot(".");

    if(result == 0)
        printf("Chroot Succese.\n");

    char *arrays[]={"./hw.out",NULL};
    execvp("./hw.out", arrays);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So what did it do instead of printing "Hello World"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`execvp` is most likely failing, probably with `ENOENT: no such file or directory`, if `hw.out` is a dynamically linked executable.

For that to work, all the libraries required by `hw.out` need to be findable in the `chroot`ed environment.

Try linking `hw.out` statically, and it should work. (And add error checking after `execvp` to see what `errno` is set to after the call if it returns.)

Comment: Thanks! I just figured it out. It's true that hw.out needs some libraries because I compile it dynamically. After compile it static, it works!

Answer (score 1):

Please test that your `hw.out` works with command line chroot.

Perhaps hw.out is dynamically linked and is missing some libraries or `ld-linux.so` in the chroot directory.

Nitpicks 1, what's the point of `return 0` after execvp? it never gets executed unless there is an error. I would rather have `perror("can't exec"); return 1;`

Nitpick 2, chroot() doesn't change working directory, although it works in your case, as you are chrooting to `"."`, it won't work as you expect if you later change it to chroot("somedir").

Comment: Thanks! I should use chdir("\\") to change the working directory. You are right that I dynamically compile the hw.out and don't have the libraries.

Comment: You should use `chdir` with the same absolute path as `chroot`, and before it. Linux paths don't use the backslash as a directory seperator, but the forward-slash.

Comment: And learn to use  `strace` both on your own binaries and on existing executables, to understand the system calls they are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that *hw.out* is in the correct direct. Perhaps it is easier to have it statically linked if it is using libraries. Otherwise need to enable after chroot that it can access the dynamic libraries.